# Sencha Touch & Google Maps API -- how to render directions as list?

Tags: google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch

All,

I'm attempting to display the text versions of the results from `Google.maps.DirectionsService.route()`.  I'm passing the `DirectionsRender` class a DOM node--a DIV-- for it to render the text to, but I'm getting a blank page.  Does anyone know of a way to pass an Ext.Panel to the `DirectionsRenderer` and get it to render?  Here's my current attempt:

```
 plotDirections: function(directionsResult, status) {

    if (status != this.ROUTING_STATUS_OK) {
        log.debug("routing blew up:  " + status);
        Ext.Msg.alert('Routing Error', 'Couldn\'t route:  ' + status, Ext.emptyFn);
        return;
    }

    var targetListDiv = this.directionsList.getEl().dom;

    this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map:this.nearMeMap.map,
        directions:directionsResult,
        suppressMarkers:true,
        panel:targetListDiv

    });

    this.showDirectionsList();

    log.debug(targetListDiv.outerHTML);


}
```

Thanks for your help!

`<rant>`
PS:  I searched the Sencha forums, but, lord, are they useless.  Not only that, but I get an error message if I execute a search more than once every 15 seconds -- I'm not allowed to execute that many at a time.  What the hey?  And insult to injury, any posts you make to the forms have to be approved.  Getting an answer to a question is nuts.
`</rant>`

Comment: My workaround is to grab the individual steps from the route's leg and call `panel.update(steps)` like so:  `  this.directionsPanel.update(directionsResult.routes[0].legs[0].steps);
`.  The template looks like this:  ` var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div>{instructions} | {distance.text}</div>',
                '</tpl>'
                );`.  any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the text to render by using the following:

Panel Code:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    flex: 1,
    html: '<div id="directionsTextHTML"></div>',
    id: 'directionsText',
    scrollable: true
}
```

Directions Function Code:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, dstatus) {
if (dstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(mapRef.getMap());
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsTextHTML'));
}
```